# How to assign a function to a method as well as pass values to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been struggling with this concept for a few days now and can hopefully put it to rest finally. High level im making a card game and when I click a card I want the card to change in opacity and I want its name added to an array. I can do this by writing 20 functions but I would like to create just one function and reuse it.

```
var box = $('#box1');
var cardsSelected = [];


function pushCard(arg1) {
  if (this.style.opacity == 0.5) {
    this.style.opacity = 1;
    cardsSelected.pop(arg1);
  } 
  else {
    this.style.opacity = 0.5;
    cardsSelected.push(arg1);
  }
}
```

I can get the opacity piece to work with this

```
box.click(pushCard);
```

and I can get the name piece to work with this

```
box.click(() => pushCard('Name'));
```

But I cannot get both to work, can anybody offer advice? Im more interested in understanding the concepts than the actual answer, thank you.

Comment: `box.click(e => pushCard(e, 'Name'));` And accept the `pushCard(event, arg1)` on the method.  Then use `event.target` in place of `this`.

Comment: You are a hero, thank you